# Converting URL Text to Clickable Hyperlink in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

Can someone please help me to modify the below to include the selected cell range from sheets. say sheet2 cell range IS B1:B200. kindly Help.

```
Sub ConvertToHyperlinks()
   ' Updated By Nirmla`
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim WorkRng As Range
   On Error Resume Next
   xTitleId = "Converrt Hyper Link"
   Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
   Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
   For Each Rng In WorkRng
      Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Rng, Rng.value
   Next
End Sub
```

I dont know anything on VBA. Kindly help.

Comment: What is your problem with this code? It seems to work.

Comment: Excel converts the text to a hyperlink automatically without the need for VBA

Comment: Welcome vinod! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ConvertToHyperlinks()
'Updated By Nirmla`
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Converrt Hyper Link"
'Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
'Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng = Range("Sheet2!B1:B200")
For Each Rng In WorkRng
Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Rng, Rng.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Or type it in the InputBox. Then no need to edit the code.
Type **Sheet2!B1:B200**